# Can the XML-based Document files be rendered in the web browser

Tags: xml, xslt, openoffice.org, odt

Open Office Document types (like `.odt`,`.ods`,...) are based on an extended version of XML.

XML documents with XSL documents can be easily used to make web browser renderable web pages.

I created an Open Office Document file with `.odt` extension and renamed it to have `.xml` extension. Assume, then I added links to appropriate XSL files in the XML document. If the XML file is opened with a browser, will it be displayed as the original `.odt` file was displayed in editors?

Are there any appropriate XSL files available for a similar purpose?

Comment: Most browsers can display XML content as XML, when the MIME type is "text/xml".  For example you can serve .XSL as "text/xml", and the browser will display the XSL content in an XML viewer (Chrome does this very well).  I'd investigate serving your .odt file with the "text/xml" mime type to instruct the browser to display as XML.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the various office suites supporting the open office format allow you to export as HTML. Whether XSLT is used to convert from XML to HTML I am not sure about; there are various other XML based formats like DocBook or DITA that use XSLT 2 or 3 to transform to HTML, so usually the transformation is done outside of the browser as these support only the ancient XSLT 1.0.